# query level 0 Name value

Tags: c#, linq

How do i find the value for name before the first of 0.
So below the answer is XXXXXX?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <mes_message>
  <msg_environment>UUUUU</msg_environment> 
- <msg_header>
  <msg_type>VscLineageResponse</msg_type> 
  <msg_stat>1</msg_stat> 
  <msg_source>M590</msg_source> 
  <msg_time>2014/10/23 09:37:44</msg_time> 
  <msg_description /> 
  <msg_string>Inquiry completed successfully</msg_string> 
  </msg_header>
- <msg_body>
- <ChildContainer>
  <Name>MEDMESC-CLN0001</Name> 
  <Level>1</Level> 
  </ChildContainer>
- <ChildContainer>
  <Name>Bay2-CLN0001</Name> 
  <Level>1</Level> 
  </ChildContainer>
- <ChildContainer>
  <Name>XXXXXX</Name> 
  <Level>0</Level> 
  </ChildContainer>
- <ChildContainer>
  <Name>Bay2-CLN0001</Name> 
  <Level>1</Level> 
  </ChildContainer>
  </msg_body>
  </mes_message
```

Comment: You find the `Element ChildContainer` that contains `element Level` whose value is 0, and return the value of its `element Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (var el in xml.Descendants("ChildContainer").Where(el => el.Element("Level").Value == "0"))
{
    string value = (string)el.Element("Name");
    ....
}
```

Comment: `var xml = XDocument.Parse(x);` where `x` is an xml string or `var xml = XDocument.Load(x)` where `x` is a path, uri or stream

Comment: it works , can i ask one further question before i mark as answer. How do i count the number of results as i must only get 1

Comment: That will loop them all, put a `break;` in the loop to exit after you deal the first.

Answer (score 2):

With XPath (please check hierarchy, without indentation I may be wrong):

```
mes_message/msg_body/ChildContainer/Level[contains(., '0')]
```

If `Level` cannot be in any other place also this works:

```
//Level[contains(., '0')]
```

Then you can get value of previous sibling node with `preceding-sibling`. In LINQ to XML you may use `XPathSelectElements("preceding-sibling::*")` or simply `ElementsBeforeSelf()`.

Answer (score 1):

one way could be something like this

```
var el = xdoc.Descendants("Name").
                FirstOrDefault(nameEL => nameEL.Parent.Name == "ChildContainer" && int.Parse(nameEL.Parent.Element("Level").Value) == 0);
```

just be careful about int.Parse(nameEL.Parent.Element("Level").Value). it is supposed be an int or you should first be sure it is int then parse it

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = xml.Descendants("ChildContainer")
                .Where(x => x.Descendants("Level").First().Value == "0")
                .Descendants("Name");
```